# Scores using Filestream (AS3 - Air for Android)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, filestream

I've started a little board game for android and i've been researching ways to permanently save scores. Everytime the user wins a game against the "AI", he/she gains a point (which can be used to unlock special pawns and boardgames). 
I tries with SharedObject but apparently they can be erased if user delete game data (or something). So I went with Filestream. I read a few posts online about it and thought I understood, but since it's not working for me, I guess I didn't :).

```
var wonGames:int; //variable I want to save

function writeObject():void { //First function to create/write in the file
    var score1:Object = new Object();
    score1.value =  wonGames; //value of object = variable value
    trace(score1.value);

    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("score1.file");
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeObject(score1);
    fileStream.close();
};


function readObject():void { //second function to read the file and modify the variable.

    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("score1.file");
    if (!file.exists) {
        return;
    }
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var score1:Object = fileStream.readObject(); 
    wonGames=score1.value;//update the variable
    fileStream.close();
};

btn26.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fnBtn26);
function fnBtn26(e: Event): void { //third function, where the winning happens
    if (winP1.currentFrame==1){ //game won
        winP1.nextFrame(); //victory screen
        readObject(); //get old value for score 1
        wonGames=wonGames+1; //update it
        trace("WonGames= "+ wonGames);
        writeObject(); //write it in file
    }
};
```

`wonGames` is updated, but when I close the app and restart it, it is back to 0. 
If you guys know what's wrong (or have another way to achieve my goal), I'm all ears. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you generate an apk with the code mentioned in your question and share it to test it, may be the problem is coming from your android device and not the code ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. https://www.dropbox.com/s/79k7umu5bjufxu4/Untitled-1.apk?dl=0  . I am going to try on another device and see. :)

Comment: It's working for me without problem, take a look [here](http://i58.tinypic.com/2zxnmu0.png). I used a tablet with Android 4.1.1 and AIR 15.

Comment: Just tried with my brother's phone and it works too. Still not on mine though. May be it's my phone, i'll try with other devices when I get the chance. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Probably “value” from wonGames=score1.value; not exists and FP evaluate it to undefined and trying to assign it to int (wonGames) return 0; 
In WriteObject try:

```
  fileStream.writeInt(score1);
```

and readObject try:

```
  wonGames =  fileStream.readInt();
```

// wonGames=score1.value;//update the variable

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your suggestion, but Flash CC tells me that there is a problem of : 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type int. (Object and int).

Comment: In which line? Are you commented:  wonGames=score1.value;//update the variable?